# Drupal - Save for Later using Workflow, conditional required fields

Tags: drupal, workflow

I have a node set up with a few workflow states. The first state, "Draft", should be used to allow someone to save the node without any required fields. The second state, "Submitted", should make the required fields active. I found a module, `Workflow Required Fields` that ALMOST handles this. The problem is, I'm using conditional fields so I can't just make every field required.

Essentially, I'd like to use default required field behavior for all states except the first "Draft". Is this something I can do programmatically with a module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this using the Workflow module and hacking the CCK required fields module a bit.

Answer (score -1):

[Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) is the module that will solve your problem. Rules module has a little steeper learning curve, but once you get a hang of it, you can do it easily.

Once you have Rules installed, check if the state is Draft then ignore the validations for required field. Else validate for required fields.

Consider using [Drafts](http://drupal.org/project/draft) module also.

Sorry regarding the previous answer, that was for [other question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5185961/multi-step-form-with-upload-save-to-node-type)