# Multistep form: from Block to Page?

Tags: drupal, forms

i want to know how to build a multistep form with first step in a block, second step on different url (example.com/step2).
I've tried webform, it seems it doesn't do multistep forms like this. Now I'm trying ctools, but also not sure it is possible with it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest `using two different forms`. The first form embedded in a block. Then in the form_submit function of `form_1` store the values in session. Then redirect to a page containing the `form_2` which might use values from from `form_1`. Remaining all the steps will be same as [multi-form submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5185961/multi-step-form-with-upload-save-to-node-type)